# how to show data like tab by tab?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I try to show xml file data in asp.net page.I took data by use post method like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "About.aspx/ReadXml",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                //data.questionName
                //data.answers
                //data.correctAnswer
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

I want to show question and its answers one by one.When click a next button, show another question and its answers.How can I do this? I am new at css and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then you could try integrating the form to wizard. Its very simple. You need to create a form dynamically using javascript and use the form to create a wizard.

```
$("#SurveyForm").formToWizard({ submitButton: 'Submit Answers' })
```

[Form To Wizard Demo](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/webform_to_wizard/)

Comment: Hımm ok.Also can I do fadeIn/fadeOut?